# Dynamically add or remove text input field and set values to an array of the main state in React JS

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks, state

I am trying to figure out how to submit an arbitrary amount of array elements, so at least one to infinity.

This is a state that gets passed at the click of a submit button:

```
const [gallery, setGallery] = useState({
    title: "",
    description: "",
    image_url: [],
  });
```

I am looping the following state...

```
const [linkInput, setLinkInput] = useState([{ id: 1, link: "" }]);
```

...like so:

```
<div className="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
          <label htmlFor="image_url">Image URLs*</label>
          {Array.isArray(linkInput) &&
            linkInput.map((input, i) => (
              <div className="input-group mb-3" key={input.id}>
                <input
                  className="form-control"
                  id="image_url"
                  type="text"
                  value={input.link}
                  required
                  onChange={(e) =>
                    onChangeLink({ ...input, link: e.target.value })
                  }
                />
                <br />
                <div style={{ color: "#ffffff" }}>__</div>
                {linkInput.length !== 1 && (
                  <>
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      className="btn btn-primary"
                      onClick={() => removeLink(input.id)}
                    >
                      Remove Image
                    </button>
                  </>
                )}
              </div>
            ))}
          <br />
          <button
            type="button"
            className="btn btn-primary"
            onClick={() => addInput()}
          >
            Add another image
          </button>
        </div>
```

These are functions I am using to add or remove input fields by modifying the "linkInput" state:

```
const handleRemoveLink = (id) => {
    setLinkInput(linkInput.filter((el) => el.id !== id));
};

  const handleAddInputField = () => {
    const lastItem = linkInput[linkInput.length - 1];
    setLinkInput([...linkInput, { id: Number(lastItem.id + 1), link: "" }]);
  };
```

I am trying to take the "link" value from each input element and place it in "image_url: []" upon clicking on submit button on my form. Currently I am not even close, the form behaves as such: it totally disappears when placing even a single character. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by mapping over the existing `linkInput` array with `map` which returns a **new** array.

```js
const handleLink = (e, index) => {
  const result = linkInput.map((linkObj, i) => {
    if (i === index) {
      // create a new object with the values of the previous link object
      // set the link prop to the new value
      return {
        ...linkObj,
        link: e.target.value,
      };
    }
    return linkObj;
  });
  setLinkInput(result);
};
```

A common mistake is to not return a **new** object and mutate the `linkObj` directly. When doing so you'll change the original object.

```js
const linkInput = [{ id: 1, link: "" }];

let result = [...linkInput];
result = result.map((x, i) => {
  if (i === 0) x.link = "mutated";
  return x;
});

console.log('linkInput',linkInput);
console.log('result',result);
```

As you can see both of the array's have the "mutated" value while did copy the list.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to specify exactly what event corresponds to what array element:

```
const handleLink = (e, index) => {
    let result = [...linkInput];
    result = result.map((x, i) => {
      if (i === index) x.link = e.target.value;
      return x;
    });
    setLinkInput(result);
  };
```

NOTE: I dropped "id" property on linkInput in favor of indexes.

Comment: This works but it is mutating the object directly. It's recommended to return a new object with the new values

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Or perhaps even show me what you mean? I thought I created a new object when I initialized "result"?